# Display button on Entity HomePageGrid in RibbonWorkBench

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365, crm-ribbon-workbench

I want to display a button on the Home Page of a custom entity called new_orders. I only want that button to show on the home page and not the form of the individual records of the custom entity. I only want it to show for that custom entity. Is EntityRule the right approach through ribbonworkbench?!

[image: RIBBON WORKBENCH]

Here is the homepage of the custom entity. I want that button to ONLY show for that custom entity, on the homepage and not on the form or subgrid.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of ribbon, Application ribbon & Entity specific ribbon. Application ribbon is global & will load for all entities, then you have to filter for specific entity.

But you are already customizing Entity specific ribbon (command bar), so no need of any special rules. It will show only on Home grid of that entity specific view. Subgrid & Form has separate command bar.

[image]